# Conditional request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, conditional-statements

I am using a Bean Shell sampler and a Bean shell preprocessor in my script.
I want my Sampler to execute only when I get the value of a parameter defined in the preprocessor.
Can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot enable or disable samplers in the runtime, basically you have 2 options:

1. Put your Beanshell Sampler under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) and set If Controller's condition elsewhere
2. Put your logic in the Beanshell Sampler inside [if-then statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) like:

   ```
   if (someValue != null) {
       //execute some code
   }
   ```

   So even if Beanshell Sampler will be executed - it will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Add HTTP request inside **if controller**, so that if value in parameter is same as value defined in preprocessor then only HTTP request will get executed